# how to remove specific pattern from string in sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have so many strings like below

```
COLGATE GRF 75 GMS (Rs. 65)( 72 PCS )
COLGATE GRF 100 GM (RS.90) - RELAUNCH( 72 PCS )
COLGATE GRF 100 GM (RS.88) COLLECTIBLES( 72 PCS )
COLGATE GRF 100 GMS (Rs. 85)( 72 PCS )
```

and want to remove (Rs. 65) and so on from string in sql. What I have try is below.

```
select SUBSTRING ('COLGATE GRF 75 GMS (Rs. 65)( 72 PCS )',0,CHARINDEX('(','COLGATE GRF 75 GMS (Rs. 65)( 72 PCS )'))
```

Comment: You want to remove the whatever in the parenthesis `()` that contain `RS` ? Or is it the first occurrence of the `parenthesis ()` And what is the expected result ?

Comment: I want to remove parenthesis that contains RS and also some string only contain RS with parenthesis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use Both `SUBSTRING` & `REPLACE` functions to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @STR VARCHAR(MAX)='COLGATE GRF 75 GMS (RS. 65)( 72 PCS )'

SELECT SUBSTRING (@STR,CHARINDEX('(',@STR),(CHARINDEX(')',@STR)-CHARINDEX('(',@STR))+1)

SELECT REPLACE (@STR,SUBSTRING (@STR,CHARINDEX('(',@STR),(CHARINDEX(')',@STR)-CHARINDEX('(',@STR))+1),'')
```

Output:

```
COLGATE GRF 75 GMS ( 72 PCS )
```

Comment: but its giving substring before (RS. 65) but i need afterward string as well like 'COLGATE GRF 75 GMS ( 72 PCS )'

Comment: @AzeemHafeez I had Edited the Code now.Plz Check

Comment: @AzeemHafeez - Plz Share your Suggestions. Did u try this Code?

Answer (score 0):

Reading your intentions as removing the first set of brackets from the string (you say nothing about all bracket) then that's simply a single statement:

```
declare @s varchar(100)='COLGATE GRF 100 GM (RS.88) COLLECTIBLES( 72 PCS )'
select Left(@s,CharIndex('(',@s)-1)+Right(@s,Len(@s)-charIndex(')',@s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the start and end of the parenthesis. For start, find using `(Rs`. After that use `STUFF()` to remove it. This will works for `(Rs ??)` as the first occurrence or not. Note that it will only remove the first occurrence.

```
SELECT  *, 
        STUFF(col, s, e - s + 1, '')
FROM    tbl t
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT s = CHARINDEX('(Rs', col)    
        ) s
        CROSS APPLY
        (
            SELECT e = CHARINDEX(')', col, s)
        ) e
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c2f06c595db8af648dacf4c9879f242e)